# map container not found Leaflet with svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

below is my code. I am using a leaflet to plot a graph in svelte. But I am getting an error "map is not defined". how can I solve this?

```
<script>
    import L from 'leaflet';
    let map;
    map = L.map("mapDemo", {
  minZoom: 4,
  maxZoom: 6
});

map.zoomControl.setPosition("bottomright");
var bounds = [
  [-10, -10],
  [10, 10]
];
map.fitBounds(bounds);
var markers = {
  id1: { title: "Marker 1", coords: [1, 0], description: "Text for marker 1" },
  id2: { title: "Marker 2", coords: [4, 2], description: "Text for marker 2" },
  id3: { title: "Marker 3", coords: [8, 8], description: "Text for marker 3" }
};

var layers = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
var titlesList = [];
var idToLayer = {};
var titleToId = {};
var idToTitle = {};
var idToText = {};

var markerOnClick = function () {
  var mId = this.options.markerId;
};

$:each(markers, function (key, val) {
  var markerOptions = {
    markerId: key,
    markerTitle: val["title"],
    markerText: val["description"]
  };

  var marker = L.marker(val["coords"], markerOptions).addTo(map);
  var popupContent = val["title"];
  // Bind popup to marker click
  marker.bindPopup(popupContent);
});

</script>
  <div id="mapDemo">
  </div>
```

Also, I would like to add an image as a background and the coordinates are plotted on the given image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap your Leaflet initialization code in [onMount](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount). The script tag runs before elements are rendered to the DOM, so the mapDemo element does not exist yet.

I'm also not sure what you're trying to do with `$:each` -- I think you're looking for `Object.entries(markers).forEach(([key, val]) => {})` instead.

Here's your script tag with onMount and the each rewritten.

```
<script>
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
import L from 'leaflet';
let map;

onMount(() => {
    map = L.map("mapDemo", {
        minZoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 6
    });

    map.zoomControl.setPosition("bottomright");
    var bounds = [
        [-10, -10],
        [10, 10]
    ];
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    var markers = {
        id1: {
            title: "Marker 1",
            coords: [1, 0],
            description: "Text for marker 1"
        },
        id2: {
            title: "Marker 2",
            coords: [4, 2],
            description: "Text for marker 2"
        },
        id3: {
            title: "Marker 3",
            coords: [8, 8],
            description: "Text for marker 3"
        }
    };
    var layers = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
    var titlesList = [];
    var idToLayer = {};
    var titleToId = {};
    var idToTitle = {};
    var idToText = {};

    var markerOnClick = function() {
        var mId = this.options.markerId;
    };

    Object.entries(markers).forEach(([key, val]) => {
        var markerOptions = {
            markerId: key,
            markerTitle: val["title"],
            markerText: val["description"]
        };

        var marker = L.marker(val["coords"], markerOptions).addTo(map);
        var popupContent = val["title"];
        // Bind popup to marker click
        marker.bindPopup(popupContent);
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: partially correct but this won't work because ```import L from 'leaflet'``` only works in browser. When the component is rendered on the server, your code returns error. Check my solution down.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the script is running before the `<div id='map' class='container'></div>` has been created.

You can added it  like this :

```
 $('.pre_map').append('<div id="map" class="container col-md-8 map"></div>');
    var map = L.map('map').setView([lat, lon], 16);

    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
    }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should import leaflet inside `onMount` async `import` function

```html
<script lang='ts'>
import { onMount } from "svelte";
let mapdivtarget: HTMLDivElement
onMount(()=>{
        const Lp = (import('leaflet'))
        Lp.then(L=>{
            const map = L.map(mapdivtarget, {
                center: [51.505, -0.09],
                zoom: 13
            });
            
            L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 19,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
            }).addTo(map);
        })
</script>

<div bind:this={mapdivtarget}></div>
```